# Javascript “Not a Constructor” Exception

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have following code:

```
class Circle
  constructor: (@center, @radius, @color) ->

  @Red: (@center, @radius) ->
    new @ center, radius, 'red'

class Point
  constructor: (@x, @y) ->
```

I can create red circle like this: `red_circle = Circle.Red(new Point(0,0), 10)`

But following code doesn't work:

```
obj = Circle.Red
red_circle = obj(new Point(0,0), 10)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Circle.Red(...)` sets `this` (`@`) to `Circle`; so `new @` = `new Circle`.

`obj(...)` does not set `this`, so `new @` is invoking `new` on something else (depending on the context).

You can fix this by binding: `obj = Circle.Red.bind(Circle)`

Answer (score 1):

When invoked as `obj()`, there's no context to the call; meaning `this` inside the function is *not* `Circle`, but rather likely `window`. You need to bind the context to preserve it:

```
obj = Circle.Red.bind Circle
```